# Win 7 installation problem

Tags: windows-7

I had Win XP installed, and I want to change it to Win 7, but I'm unable to install it.
I got this message:

"File: /$LDR$

Status:OxOOOOOOf

Info: The selected entry missing or corrupt."

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your media is corrupted.
How exactly are you installing Windows 7? Is it from a DVD? Did you burn it from an .ISO file? In that case, you should try re-burning it at the slowest speed possible. Also, make sure the .ISO file itself is not corrupted by checking it with the checksum (if you have one).

Comment: It's from a burned DVD (.iso file).
I already installed Win 7 on my laptop from the same DVD and it works perfectly.
What is cheksum?

Comment: you can check the integrity of a file with the checksum, however, if the disk works fine in another computer, then it's most likely the DVD drive, replace the drive or burn another disk and try again.

Comment: This DVD works fine in that computer till almost the end of installation, then, when the screen should be showing "Windows startup" or something like that, it turnes black and stays that way.

Comment: "I already installed ... from the same DVD" is not evidence the DVD is (still) good. Your laptop may have a better reader (quite common) and/or the DVD may have been damaged later.

Comment: Could it be some hardware problem? I couldn't install Win 7, so I installed Win XP, and I also had some problems installing it, but in the end, succeded.

Comment: Possible. Depends on what the problems you encountered exactly were.